# Script not running on startup when using crontab -e

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spotipy

I have a raspberry pi and an RFID reader. I have a python script that uses RFID and spotipy to read RFID tags and plays a song/song when a certain RFID tag is scanned. I'm trying to make this python script run on startup using crontab -e so I don't have to run it everytime. I followed a tutorial online and used an example script. The example runs on start up. When I substitute it for the player script however it does not work. This is what I had in the crontab -e `@reboot python3 /home/pi/Documents/rfidspotify/player.py`. Here's the player python script I was using.(script works fine when I run it)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from time import sleep

DEVICE_ID="YOUR_DEVICE_ID"
CLIENT_ID="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
CLIENT_SECRET="YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"

while True:
    try:
        reader=SimpleMFRC522()
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                                                       client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                                                       redirect_uri="http://localhost:8080",
                                                       scope="user-read-playback-state,user-modify-playback-state"))
        
        # create an infinite while loop that will always be waiting for a new scan
        while True:
            print("Waiting for record scan...")
            id= reader.read()[0]
            print("Card Value is:",id)
            sp.transfer_playback(device_id=DEVICE_ID, force_play=False)
            
            # DONT include the quotation marks around the card's ID value, just paste the number
            if (id=='RFID-CARDVALUE-1'):
                
                # playing a song
                sp.start_playback(device_id=DEVICE_ID, uris=['spotify:track:2vSLxBSZoK0eha4AuhZlXV'])
                sleep(2)
                
            elif (id=='RFID-CARDVALUE-2'):
                
                # playing an album
                sp.start_playback(device_id=DEVICE_ID, context_uri='spotify:album:0JGOiO34nwfUdDrD612dOp')
                sleep(2)
                
            # continue adding as many "elifs" for songs/albums that you want to play

    # if there is an error, skip it and try the code again (i.e. timeout issues, no active device error, etc)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

    finally:
        print("Cleaning  up...")
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Which tutorial were you using? I find most cron issues are because the environment hasn't been fully set up so you may need to use the full `/usr/bin/python3` when running python from your crontab.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVPAHI9on0o

Comment: Ok. Nice quick tutorial. Try redirecting the output to a file to see what is happening. `@reboot python3 /home/pi/myscript.py >/home/pi/mylog.txt 2>&1 `